# Is it possible to cast MediaStream to chromecast?

Tags: javascript, casting, chromecast, google-cast

Is it possible to cast a local [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/MediaStream) to chromecast?
if so how? do i need to load the game sdk for that?

I have only figure out how to cast url's to chromecast but i want to mirror a stream from webcam

```
// stream I want to cast
var mediaStream = elm.captureStream()
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope, one way of solving it is to create a WebRTC connection and do some magic. Know how to solve but haven't done anything

Answer (score 0):

You can cast local media streams. You will have to provide a HTTP endpoint, which typically involves hosting a local web server. You can then provide a URL with a local IP address for media playback. Note, that you have to ensure you web server is secured.

Comment: Seems like there is a new cool api called [RemotePlayback](https://w3c.github.io/remote-playback/) unfortunately it's disabled on mac. I think i'm going to build a custom reciver app that talks WebRTC... has stuff like media streams. Then you don't need a local server. and every user don't have to install one either

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you stream from a webserver with an HTTP endpoint that supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
I've created a simple wrapper around the chromecast SDK:
https://github.com/Fenny/ChromecastJS

```
var cc = new ChromecastJS()
cc.on('available', function() {
    cc.cast({
        content: 'http://127.0.0.1/stream'
    })
})
```

The wrapper is really small (5.51 KB minified)

Good luck!

Comment: I don't want to have to create a local server to be able to cast something. I'm more looking into creating a p2p connection with chromecast using WebRTC right now. That means i have to create a custom reciver